# How to get longitude and latitude from address in angular - ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, geolocation, ionic4

I have the following code that I have built on ionic 4. It works for the Andriod device however it does not work for IOS.

I have found out that for IOS to work I need to work out the longitude and latitude and pass that in.

I tried a test and hardcoded the longitude and latitude and it works on the IOS device.

However, I need a way to get the longitude and latitude from a location.

I have seen geolocation but that does not pass in a location.

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
this.geolocation.watchPosition()
```

This is my code, how can I get the longitude and latitude from the location?

```
location = '10 Downing St, Westminster, London'

GoToUrl(location) {
   if (this.platform.is('android')) {
     window.location.href = 'geo:' + '?q=' + location;
   } 
   else {
     const destination = '51.503391' + ',' + '-0.127630';
     window.open('maps://?q=' + destination + '_system');
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: You need to initiate javascript maps sdk with places, and then you can fetch the location lnglat from place added .

Comment: using import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';